# strpos not returning proper result

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec, strpos

I have been bashing my head against google trying to figure this out and all I can find is people who don't understand that strpos returns the position of the found string so 0 is a valid value. That is not my problem.... in short:

```
$services=shell_exec('ps aux | grep udp');
print_r(is_string($services));
print_r($services);
```

Returns:

```
1
root       833  0.0  0.1   1852   768 ?        S    19:25   0:00 daemon -r -n udp-server1 /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php wifi:3333:true:true.
root       834  0.0  0.1   1852   768 ?        S    19:25   0:00 daemon -r -n udp-server2 /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php network:13000:false:false.
root       848 48.6  2.3  37036 11744 ?        R    19:25  18:07 /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php wifi:3333:true:true.
root       849 48.6  2.3  37064 11780 ?        R    19:25  18:07 /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php network:13000:false:false.
www-data  1675  0.0  0.0   1368   444 ?        S    20:02   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep udp
www-data  1677  0.0  0.1   1456   528 ?        S    20:02   0:00 grep udp
```

That is the result I expect, however:

```
$statuses=explode("\n",file_get_contents('/var/www/misc/udp-settings.inc'));
print_r($statuses);
foreach($statuses as $status){
    print_r(strpos($services,$status)===false);
}
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => wifi:3333:true:true [1] => network:13000:false:false [2] => )
1
1
1
```

Which is obviously wrong since the strings absolutely exist in the haystack. I have also tried stripos, mb_strpos, mb_stripos and preg_match with similar results... I have checked everything with is_string and it all checks out. I have also appended '' to the end of each string and wrapped each string with double quotes in an attempt to type cast both strings so they match (not sure if that even makes sense, but I am getting desperate LoL).

I am at a loss, I suspect there is something to do with how the udp-settings.inc file is encoded maybe, but I'm not really sure... I'm running out of things to try and could really use some help, has anyone else had this type of issue?

EDIT:

To be clear I know this works if I copy and paste the strings directly into the php file, however that isn't an option in production. One other thing I did try was exploding and imploding the value of $statuses which gives me the same result.

As mentioned in the comment below, strlen returns the appropriate results, I also checked the strings with mb_detect_encoding and they all return ASCII

Comment: Could you post the content of `/var/www/misc/udp-settings.inc`.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder he did `Array ( [0] => wifi:3333:true:true [1] => network:13000:false:false [2] => )`

Comment: Oh, totally overlooked that one, thanks.

Comment: Maybe `udp-settings.inc` has extra whitespace at the end of the line. Use `var_dump` rather than `print_r` to get a more accurate view of the data.

Comment: there is a \n at the end, I actually do check to make sure the line isn't empty, but that isn't the problem since I'm checking every line of the file and they all return false, not just the final line

Comment: I would suggest you to temporarily remove `===false` after `strpos(...)` and append `echo strlen($status);` in `foreach` loop body.

Comment: both $services and the individual $status have an appropriate length

Comment: @hindmost Thank you... you where on the right track there was a hidden character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me just fine give it a try (the only real difference is the `trim` on status and the verification for empty entries on the array as well as the if/echo for the found/not found):

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/101474)

```
<?php
$services = <<<DATA
root       833  0.0  0.1   1852   768 ?        S    19:25   0:00 daemon -r -n udp-server1 /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php wifi:3333:true:true.
root       834  0.0  0.1   1852   768 ?        S    19:25   0:00 daemon -r -n udp-server2 /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php network:13000:false:false.
root       848 48.6  2.3  37036 11744 ?        R    19:25  18:07 /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php wifi:3333:true:true.
root       849 48.6  2.3  37064 11780 ?        R    19:25  18:07 /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php network:13000:false:false.
www-data  1675  0.0  0.0   1368   444 ?        S    20:02   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep udp
www-data  1677  0.0  0.1   1456   528 ?        S    20:02   0:00 grep udp
DATA;

$statuses = <<<DATA
wifi:3333:true:true
network:13000:false:false

DATA;

$status = explode("\n",$statuses);
print_r($status);

foreach($status as $current_status)
{
    $new_status = trim($current_status);
    if (empty($new_status))
        continue;

    if (strpos($services,$new_status)!==false)
    {
        echo $new_status, " was found...\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $new_status, " was not found...\n";
    }
}
```

And with your code it should look like:

```
<?php
$services = shell_exec('ps aux | grep udp');
$statuses = explode("\n",file_get_contents('/var/www/misc/udp-settings.inc'));
$status = explode("\n",$statuses);
foreach($status as $current_status)
{
    $new_status = trim($current_status);
    if (empty($new_status))
        continue;

    if (strpos($services,$new_status)!==false)
    {
        echo $new_status, " was found...\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $new_status, " was not found...\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_filter()` is expensive, I'd rather check for empty values after `trim()` as you're already looping over the whole array.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder works too I was actually going to embed the trim with the removal of empty fields.

Comment: And then there are those problems that make you feel like you may have lost some perspective LoL. I added the trim in and this was perfect... apparently there was an extra character that didn't get copied when I copy and pasted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm your findings, just tested with latest PHP:

```
<?php

$haystack =
  "root       833  0.0  0.1   1852   768 ?        S    19:25   0:00 daemon -r -n udp-server1 /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php wifi:3333:true:true.
  root       834  0.0  0.1   1852   768 ?        S    19:25   0:00 daemon -r -n udp-server2 /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php network:13000:false:false.
  root       848 48.6  2.3  37036 11744 ?        R    19:25  18:07 /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php wifi:3333:true:true.
  root       849 48.6  2.3  37064 11780 ?        R    19:25  18:07 /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/ncd/udp-server.php network:13000:false:false.
  www-data  1675  0.0  0.0   1368   444 ?        S    20:02   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep udp
  www-data  1677  0.0  0.1   1456   528 ?        S    20:02   0:00 grep udp"
;

foreach ([ "wifi:3333:true:true", "network:13000:false:false" ] as $needle) {
  var_dump(strpos($haystack, $needle));
  echo PHP_EOL;
  var_dump((strpos($haystack, $needle) === false));
  echo PHP_EOL , PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

### Output

```
int(118)
bool(false)

int(257)
bool(false)
```

Comment: I understand that, if I copy and paste the result of print_r into a test scenario it works as expected. Which is why I'm wondering if there is some encoding issue with either the return of shell_exec or file_get_contents

Comment: `shell_exec()` will return in ASCII and if your file isn't in some really, really exotic ASCII incompatible encoding nothing bad should happen.